# Choose between multiple devices in XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, development-environment, device

I've 2 devices (iPhone + iPod) connected to my Mac and both are available as developper devices in XCode. How can I choose which one to use for testing purpose and switch from one to the other when I want ? For the moment the only way I found is to unplug the unwanted one in order for the other to be available. Am I missing something obvious ?
Rgd

--GQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is use the Overview drop-down in Xcode.  When you have multiple provisioned devices attached and have chosen to deploy to a Device (not the simulator), the drop-down will give you a choice under "Active Executable", listing the devices by name.

Comment: Great! I think this is a new feature, I can't remember if it was available in previous XCode versions (I use 3.2.2 today). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple devices but don't have enough USB ports to plug them both in at the same time. So I switch between them the same way you do...

Answer (score 0):

You use Project > Set Active Executable, and pick the device you want.  In order for a device to show up, it has to be provisioned with a copy of the OS and the provisioning file that corresponds to the target OS and signing certificate for the app you built.

Comment: Sorry but I can't find anything useful here. Set Active Executable only shows my... executables... no reference to my 2 connected and provisionned devices. Can you explain what you mean exactly ?